# Enforce sRGB for images in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, srgb, color-management

I am using Format (https://www.format.com), a managed service for my photo portfolio website https://www.the-ninth.com.

To that website, I upload images in the sRGB color space. Unfortunately Format will strip any color space information from the images after the upload. Browsers will get the images untagged and most browsers will apply sRGB anyway and therefore display the images correctly.

However, Firefox is an exception here, Firefox will use the monitor color space. So especially on wide gamut monitors, Firefox will display over-saturated colors by default. Only if the configuration setting gfx.color_management.mode is changed from "2" to "1" Firefox will apply sRGB to untagged images. But of course I cannot rely on my users doing that.

Is there any code I can embed in my website to force Firefox to apply sRGB color space to untagged images? I do have full access to the  element of the website and could add HTML/CSS/Javascript elements there.

Regards, Robert

Comment: you can at least warn with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/dynamic-range you might even be able to tone down the saturation with a filter inside a high dr query section. something like `@media (dynamic-range: high) { img { filter:saturate(0.85); }}`

Comment: Not an answer, but consider to change service. If your photo are mangled, you do not known the final quality. ICC profile, copyright information, compression, etc. In short: for a portfolio you should have control on what your client will see: it is to show your work and its quality (then for printing, selling, etc. things are different).

Comment: Thanks - I will look at the dynamic range property and see if I can present the user with a warning. I am also in touch with my service provider and maybe I'll be able to get them to fix it.